Chrome auto-filling input fields even after setting the autocomplete ="OFF"?
I have a form in my web application where users can search for items. The form consists of an input field with the placeholder "smHRt searcHR" and a search button. Initially, the input field had the ID "smHRtsearcHR", but I noticed that Chrome was auto-filling this field even though I had set autocomplete="off".
To address this issue, I changed the ID of the input field multiple times, but after 10 to 12 days, Chrome starts auto-filling the field again. I've ensured that autocomplete="off" is set both on the  tag and the input field itself.
Here's the HTML structure of my form:
<form role="search" class="search" data-toggle="collapse" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="smHRtsearcHR" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="smHRt searcHR..." class="form-control global-searchbox">
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
</form>

this is the image of that field
I've researched this issue and found suggestions such as changing the name attribute or using JavaScript to clear the input field on page load, but these solutions seem more like workarounds rather than addressing the root cause.
I'm looking for insights on why Chrome continues to auto-fill the input field and how I can prevent this behavior reliably. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

instead of autocomplete="off" you need to use autocomplete="new-password"


<input type="text" autocomplete="new-password" />



In Chrome, autocomplete="off" disables autocomplete but keeps autofill enabled. Autocomplete="new-password" prevents autofilling.

according to documentation - "new-password" is not a supported value for the autocomplete attribute in any browser other than Firefox - and even if it were supported, it's not the right value to use
